# Why is Enum not evaluating properly inside *ngFor loop, but evaluates fine outside loop?

Tags: angular

I'm seeing what appears to be some strange behavior regarding evaluation of my Enum in template. The Enum evaluates properly outside my `*ngFor` loop, but not inside the loop.

Template (`details.component.ts`):

```
      <div class="member-section-header">
        Section #: {{datColEnum.sectionCol}}   <-- THIS EVALUATES PROPERLY
        <ng-container *ngFor="let dat of datArr">
          Section # Again: {{datColEnum.sectionCol}}   <-- THIS DOESN'T EVALUATE PROPERLY
```

Component (`details.component.ts`):

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'; 

. . . 

enum datCols {
  formatTypeCol = 0,
  labelCol,
  nameCol,
  dimensionCol,
  valueCol,
  enumCol,
  controlNameCol,
  placeholderCol,
  sectionCol
 }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.scss']
})

export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit  {
public datColEnum = datCols; 

. . .
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me, but only if datArr has at least one element as if datArr has no data then you don't iterate over anything.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaznf3

Comment: Thank you.  `datArr` definitely has data and is definitely iterating, but whereas I get `Section #: 8` outside the loop, inside the loop I get several iterations of: `Section # Again:` (with just a blank where the `8` should be). So for some reason, it's not working for me inside the loop. But interesting that you couldn't reproduce that behavior. I'm trying to dig deeper. It just doesn't make sense!

Comment: My sincere apologies. Something else buried further down the code was giving an error, which made it look like the Enum wasn't evaluating properly, but after I fixed the other error, the enum is now evaluating properly.